# Grep: Search between "beginning of a paragraph" and colon :

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I try to apply a style to a string of words that is beginning a paragraph and before a colon.

I prepared a first Grep search but it is not working (it is only placing the cursor before the colon without selecting anything...

```
(?=^)*?(?=\:)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beginning you have `(?=^)`. A *Positive Lookahead* that looks ahead to see if a *Beginning of Paragraph* comes *after* whatever text you have before the lookahead (in this case none). Then you have `*?` which searches for *Zero or More Times (Shortest Match)* of that *Positive Lookahead*. It's a bit malformed. You don't actually select any characters.

For your approach to work you would have to use a *Positive Lookbehind* `(?<=^)` that looks behind to see if a *Beginning of Paragraph* comes *before* the text without selecting it. Then use `.*?` to select any character *Zero or More Times (Shortest Match)* and a *Positive Lookahead* `(?=:)` to end the selection before a colon:

`(?<=^).*?(?=:)`

But you can write it simpler. `^` is always non-matching, so you don't need the lookbehind:

`^.*?(?=:)`

Comment: `^` itself is non-matching, so it’s not necessary to do a lookbehind at all – in fact, I wouldn’t have thought a lookbehind for a `^` would even work at all. Your version will also match non-initial strings, though (i.e., if there are two colons, it will match the string between them), so a `^` is needed. `*?` is perfectly valid: it’s a non-greedy wildcard match. You could even use this to make the query a bit simpler: `^.*?:` will match the same as `^[^:]*:` (including the colon), and `^.*?(?=:)` will match the same as your `^[^:]*(?=:)` (with the extra `^`).

Comment: I’m guessing the reason why the original query just places the cursor before the colon is that `(?=^)` by definition cannot match anything, but is apparently not invalid syntactically, so it’s equivalent to an empty, non-matching group. This empty group (= anything that’s not a non-empty match, i.e., any position between characters) is then matched non-greedily up until a position where it’s followed by a colon (from the lookahead) – that is, the position between the colon and the character immediately preceding it. Definitely _not_ normal use of GREP, though!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, using the non-greedy wildcard `*?` is nice, but I don't understand why you feel the need to have `^` in the beginning. To me it seems that `.*?(?=:)` works just as well as `^.*?(?=:)`. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/i1iztnI.png) and notice how it doesn't select the string between the colons. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, and please, if I say something wrong about GREP in my answer, don't hesitate to fix it!

Comment: That’s in a GREP _style_, which only matches once per paragraph. The question mentions a GREP _search_, which will match multiple times per paragraph (unless the query contains a paragraph mark or `$`, of course). If you do a find/replace-all with the same query, it should match the string between the colons as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Whoops! I understand. My answer is a mess then.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I edited. Is it correct now?

Comment: Looks good to me!